# How to send a string and binary literals to a server in Java

Tags: java, sockets, binary, arrays, bytebuffer

I have a situation where I have a String and three binary literals i need to add to a Byte array to send to a server.

The Client:

```
    String arbitrary = "/AN/ARBITRARY/STRING";
    int b_f32b = 0b00000000000000000000000011111111;
    int b_seconds = 0b00000000000000001111111111111111;
    int b_fraction = 0b01000000000000000000000000000000;

    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);

    bb.put(arbitrary.getBytes());
    bb.putInt(b_f32b);
    bb.putInt(b_seconds);
    bb.putInt(b_fraction);

    bb.clear();
    byte[] sendDataBytes = new byte[bb.capacity()];
    bb.get(sendDataBytes, 0, sendDataBytes.length);

    DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendDataBytes, sendData.length, IPAddress, 7000);
    clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
```

On the Server:

```
        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
        serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
        String sentence = new String( receivePacket.getData());
```

The result is:
RECEIVED: /AN/ARBITRARY/STRING ÿ ÿÿ@

The String works fine - but the binary values do not is there something fundamental I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the fundamental understanding between binary and character data.

Strings are character data, meaning they're displayable. Binary data is not necessary displayable (especially in this case, since you know that you're not writing character data).

The `putInt()` method puts 4 bytes in the buffer. Read it with `getInt()` and then you'll get a value you can display.

Edit:

You're also creating a 1024 byte array with `byte[] sendDataBytes = new byte[bb.capacity()];` and sending that over the wire. You'll never know how much of the 1024 bytes are actual data, and how much is just empty garbage.

Yes, you're missing a lot of fundamentals here and it's too broad to address everything in an answer.

Comment: could you offer a small example? I don't think I am following

Comment: Your `b_f32b` is transferred as binary data, i.e. `0x000000FF`. That won't convert to a character nicely, so when you convert your datagram message into a String (which is completely wrong), it shows up like that.

Comment: any insight on how this could be possible?

Comment: @Hughzi How what could be possible?

Comment: Accessing sent binary of a fixed length

Comment: Well, you have so many problems right now that I don't even know where to start. Sending oversized packets, not understanding the difference between binary and text, no working protocol... You'd probably manage a lot better by using `DataOutputStream` and `DataInputStream` over a TCP connection instead.

Comment: I am using this UDP tutorial as a basis https://systembash.com/a-simple-java-udp-server-and-udp-client/ the requirment is to send a packet made up of contiguous sections of multiples of 4 bytes long.

Comment: The tutorial only sends character data between the peers, that's why it can display the transferred data as a `String`. You can't do that since you added binary data to the mix (or at least you need to separate the character data from the binary data somehow (which is your problem)).